# При запуске команды make VS Code постоянно зависает на одном и том же месте

Tags: mysql, makefile

```
db_1           | 2022-01-21T16:27:02.275110Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
db_1           | 2022-01-21T16:27:02.523271Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
db_1           | 2022-01-21T16:27:02.524438Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
db_1           | Version: '5.7.35-38'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  Percona Server (GPL), Release 38, Revision 3692a61
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ну вообще зависит от того, что там в Makefile